# How to count number of unique groups missing information in a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = [
    ["AB", np.nan, 134, "ID1"],
    ["AB", np.nan, 252, "ID1"],
    ["BC", np.nan, 56, "ID2"],
    ["CD", np.nan, 159, "ID1"],
    ["DE", 32, np.nan, "ID3"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["method", "var_1", "var_2", "ID"])
df
```

I am trying to get a count of unique IDs grouped by method which have missing values for `var_1` and `var_2` and am unable to find a way to do this.

I have been able to get counts of missing data using `count()` and `size()` and subtracting one from the other, but unfortunately I really need counts of unique IDs. It seems so simple I feel as though I must be missing something obvious!

My desired output is:

Where we are grouping by method and counting the number of unique IDs missing information for the other columns.

```
method  var_1  var_2
  AB      1      0
  BC      1      0
  CD      1      0
  DE      0      1
```

Comment: Your test data isn't the best for the requirement that you count unique IDs. Basically you'd get the same answer if you just count nulls. Might be worth changing the first 121 to np.nan, which I think keeps your desired output identical, but illustrates that unique IDs is the thing you want to count, not nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count unique IDs, check where it's null then `max` within [ID, method], to indicate any missing value within that [ID, method]. Then sum over the method to get the Number of unique IDS missing something.

```
(df[['var_1', 'var_2']].isnull()
    .groupby([df['ID'], df['method']]).max()
    .sum(level='method')
```

---

```
        var_1  var_2
method              
AB          1      0
CD          1      0
BC          1      0
DE          0      1
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case

```
g = df.groupby(['ID','method'])
out = g[['var_1','var_2']].apply(lambda x : x.isnull().sum())
            var_1  var_2
ID  method              
ID1 AB          1      0
    CD          1      0
ID2 BC          1      0
ID3 DE          0      1
```